# Why ChunkSpy .function part has four parameters?

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

When using ChunkSpy, I find one thing makes me coufused. Let's see the following example

```
>a = 1
; source chunk: (interactive mode)
; x86 standard (32-bit, little endian, doubles)

; function [0] definition (level 1)
; 0 upvalues, 0 params, 2 stacks
.function  0 0 2 2
.const  "a"  ; 0
.const  1  ; 1
[1] loadk      0   1        ; 1
[2] setglobal  0   0        ; a
[3] return     0   1
; end of function
```

Since here is `0 upvalues, 0 params, 2 stacks`, why there are four parameters in `.function  0 0 2 2`

In another example, we can see that

```
>local a; function b() a = 1 return a end
; source chunk: (interactive mode)
; x86 standard (32-bit, little endian, doubles)

; function [0] definition (level 1)
; 0 upvalues, 0 params, 2 stacks
.function  0 0 2 2
.local  "a"  ; 0
.const  "b"  ; 0

; function [0] definition (level 2)
; 1 upvalues, 0 params, 2 stacks
.function  1 0 0 2
.upvalue  "a"  ; 0
.const  1  ; 0
[1] loadk      0   0        ; 1
[2] setupval   0   0        ; a
[3] getupval   0   0        ; a
[4] return     0   2
[5] return     0   1
; end of function

[1] closure    1   0        ; 1 upvalues
[2] move       0   0
[3] setglobal  1   0        ; b
[4] return     0   1
; end of function
```

So I guess the first parameter is upvalues, but what is the use of the second?

Comment: The second is the number of named parameters. Try `function b(x,y,z)` and you will see `3`

Comment: The third is sum of flags: 1=VARARG_HASARG, 2=VARARG_ISVARARG, 4=VARARG_NEEDSARG

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff  Thanks for your comments, it's really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer by the help of Egor Skriptunoff from comments.

The .fucntion part with four parameters are meaning like below:

- number of upvales
- number of named parameters
- flag of arg : 1=VARARG_HASARG, 2=VARARG_ISVARARG, 4=VARARG_NEEDSARG. It's always 0 for normal function, and 2 for main function chunk.
- number of stacks